# Migrate from lucene.net 3.0 to 4.8

Tags: lucene.net

We are upgrading from lucene.net 3.0 to 4.8. Now we have some issues because of breaking changes between these versions.

1. In our project, we make use of the `CustomScoreQuery` which used to be part of the `Lucene.Net.Search.Function` namespace. It is no longer there. According to the [Apache documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_4_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/CustomScoreQuery.html) is is deprecated and should be replaced by using the `FunctionScoreQuery`, but this class doesn't seem to exist in 4.8. What should we use instead?
2. We used a custom collector class, that inherited from `Lucene.Net.Search.Collector`. In 4.8, this class has become sealed. I see there a several implementation classes. Which one should I use?

   *I discovered I need to use the `ICollector` interface. Which partly solves the problem. In the `SetNextReader` function, we use to do something like `Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetStrings(reader, "<field>")`. This has also been removed. Apparently we need to use `Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCache.DEFAULT.GetTerms(context.AtomicReader, "<fieldid>", false)`. So this issue seems solved*
3. We used a class that inherited from `CustomScoreProvider` in `Lucene.Net.Search.Function`, but it is no longer there in 4.8. We used it combined with the `CustomScoreQuery` as returnvalue for the `GetCustomScoreProvider` method There doesn't seem to be any alternative. What should we use instead?
4. We used a WhitespaceAnalyzer in 3.0, Which doesn't seem to be there anymore. What is the replacement for that?

There is [some documentation](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00013/), but unfortunately the link to the migration guide is still a TODO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted my questions [here](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/398), and the nice people from lucene.net answered all my questions